# Create select statement based on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create some overviews and eventually some dynamic select statements for a database.

```
select 'select ''' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ''', count(*) from [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] union all'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_TYPE != 'VIEW'
  and (select count(*) from TABLE_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME) > 0
```

I'm stuck on this part: `select count(*) from TABLE_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME`
Which throws *Invalid object name*

Is there any way I can make that work dynamically?

Comment: I think you don't need that part, just remove it ;).

Comment: This is just an example, I do need it...

Comment: `TABLE_SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME` will search for a table name `TABLE_NAME` in schema `TABLE_SCHEMA` which is an invalid object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude tables with no rows from your result set, add a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0` clause to your generated SQL:

```
select 'select ''' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ''', count(*) from [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] having count(*) > 0 union all'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_TYPE != 'VIEW'
```